# Protecting recursive operations from cycles

Tags: c#, .net

Our code allows a user to set a parameter and its value.
A value may be a reference to another parameter.

```
Parameter.Set("Parameter1", "%Parameter2%");
Parameter.Set("Parameter2", "%Parameter1%");
```

The actual resolving of this value uses Regex class's Replace method to resolve any references inside % symbols recursively, and replace them:

```
// Pseudo code (the actual parameter name is retrieved and replaced with its value.
Regex.Replace("%Parameter1%", match => Parameter.Get(match));
```

In this case, a cyclic reference will cause a StackOverflowException.

How can this be avoided? (In case a cyclic reference is detected - throw an exception/handle in some way)

A proposed implementation was to keep a list of terms that were already looked for in the current resolving execution (a "Search History").

For each step, look if the current searched parameter is in the history, if it is -- we've looked at it  already, and we must be in a cycle.

The downside to this approach is that it's wasteful (allocate a new List for each parameter resolving that occurs).

Comment: I am looking for specific patterns (text enclosed in a specific symbol, say percent). Regex helps me identify & replace all of these in a single method call.

Comment: You're looking for a specific substring and want to replace it. string.Replace() can do that. Why do you use Regex.Replace()?

Comment: Using string.Replace makes no difference, as for each string replacement, i need to resolve the actual value for the parameter, following a similar logic.

Comment: Oh, no, it's unrelated to the question exactly. There is no reason to use Regex.Replace() when you can use string.Replace(). string.Replace() gets you predictable performance. Regex.Replace() can explode.
The answer to the problem you proposed, is to use a counter. Instead of Parameter.Get, use Parameter.Get(x, int). Explicitly limit the number of times you can evaluate a parameter. This will allow you to void the more complex cycles.

Comment: Thanks. That is one approach i haven't considered. Although the user MAY be able to define a chain of 20 parameters referring to one another. Where do i set the limit exactly? this approach is somewhat of a guesswork.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11951/discussion-between-greg-ros-and-lysergic-acid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested above, rewrite the signature of the recursive method as `Parameter.Get(string, int)`. Use the int as a recursion depth counter. Each time the method needs to evaluate a deeper parameter, decrement the int variable. When it reaches 0, stop processing parameters. The initial value of int can be a pretty small number, since few people will use 20 recursive parameters.